# IEx.configure equivalent for mix test?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When debugging tests, it's easy to put some `IO.inspect` statements in there to see what's going on. This works great, until objects grow too big.

What is the `mix` equivalent of `iex`'s `IEx.configure [inspect: [limit: 1000]]` when running `mix test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEx.configure [inspect: [limit: 1000]]` only changes the options for the automatic `inspect` call made by `iex` for every expression entered, and does not change the behavior of the actual `IO.inspect` function. You'll have to create a wrapper around `IO.inspect` and use that instead of `IO.inspect`:

```
test "the truth" do
  list = Enum.to_list(1..100)
  IO.inspect list
  i list
end

defp i(item, opts \\ []) do
  IO.inspect(item, Keyword.put(opts, :limit, 1000))
end
```

Output:

```
$ mix test
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
.

Finished in 0.03 seconds
1 test, 0 failures
```